# Spark Dataframe Writing to MySQL with SaveMode.Append along with duplicate records

Tags: apache-spark

Trying to writing into an existing MySQL table, possibly with some duplicated records.

```
df.write
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .jdbc(jdbcUrl, db_table, connectionProperties)
```

What I want is an "insert ignore". But it seems SaveMode.Append won't tolerate duplicates. SaveMode.Ignore won't work, as it's the whole table that it ignores. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any solution around this?? I am trying from Glue. So glue dynamic frame or spark dataframe needs to be written in RDS mysql with ignoring duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

A well-known issue.

I have a requirement to UPSert to mySQL in some minor cases.

What I did was in such cases:

1. Process in SPARK and save results to tempview or process the outcomes in Dataframe / DataSet.
2. Save from Step 1 to a temporary mySQL table.
3. Execute a mutate statement from SPARK performing an UPSert on and in mySQL environment from temporary table to final table at rest in mySQL.

That is the best I got. There are other approaches, but this is one such approach.

I was talking in generic terms, so for mySQL as there is no UPSert I used this type of approach:

```
insert into t1(a, b, c)
select d, e, f from t2
on duplicate key update b = e, c = f;
```

via a mutate statement. Not quite SPARK, but well we have to make do at times!

Comment: Could you be more specific on step-3? Do you mean read the temporary mysql table and upsert the final table, using Spark?

Comment: No, I mean execute a mutate statement from SPARK. Now there is no UPSert in mysql but something else. I will update the answer.